# Importing entire folder of excel files WITH sourcefile names in Access table onClick using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filenames, ms-access-2013, import-from-excel

[Import entire folder of Excel files into Access 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510984/import-entire-folder-of-excel-files-into-access-2013)

The question above has answered half of my question, but now, I need to import all the file names along with the cell references I'm importing. For every line that is taken from excel, I would like the source file name to appear beside it, in the same table.

For context, I am importing only section B147:I161 on one sheet of all excel workbooks, for 74 files. 
I have searched all of the questions regarding importing excel information into Access and have come up empty handed.

thank you

Comment: I'd suggest copying B147:I161 to B1:I14 in a new sheet, and making A1:A14 value = filename. Then import that sheet.

Comment: Since these excel files are not owned by me and there are so many of them and they are often changing, I cannot change each one. Otherwise I would just copy the necessary information into access by hand.

Comment: I think you missed the point I was making. Automate the copying of the data into another sheet/workbook and the setting of the data into column A. Alternatively, loop through your imports and after each file run an update query to set any blank fieldnames to the value of the filename.

Comment: oooh, yes I did miss your point. thank you!